# How to position text specifically in Bootstrap Jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my Jumbotron, I would like to have some text pinned to the bottom left corner of the Jumbotron. I have some `max-width` & `max-height` properties that I think might be the issue, but i'm not really sure. I've gotten it sort of in the code below, but when the page is resized it the text moves off of the Jumbotron or positions all wonky.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
<div class="six">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="jumbotron">
  </a>
    <h5>Text</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .six .jumbotron
    { background: url("Img") no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-width: 220px;
    max-width:250px;
    min-height:260px;
    max-height:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 3em auto;
    }

 `  .six .jumbotron > h5{
  position:absolute;
  color:#000;
  left:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  font-size:15px;
}`
```

Comment: Could you please make a JSFiddle or something similar with your code? There's a lot that goes into CSS, and it can be hard to debug without actually being able to "play" with the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you position the H5 absolute to the page and not to the element, to fix it do this: Fiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/agc3e3yp/2/

```
 .jumbotron h5{
 margin-top:90%; 
 left:10px;
 font-size:15px;
 color:#fff;
}
```

**Note** the text will still move around, but that is because the parent element is changing size when you change screen size. but now it will stay inside the box at 90% of it's height. Best bet is just put your text in a div and style it yourself.

Let me know it works for you :)